# JS for Sliding Content From Nav

Tags: javascript, slide, nav

Basically, I have been trying to find a JS Fiddle for sliding in content selected from the navigation. I have attached a link to something like I was looking for in terms of sliding the content. In short, I am going to have an About Page with a sub navigation on the page for 4 content boxes. I want to slide this boxes in and off the screen when a new section is selected. For instance Content Box 1 is visible first, if someone navigates to Box 4, 1 will slide off, 2 will slide by, 3 will slide by and 4 will slide on. I think the link is exactly what I was looking for. Any help would be great. Thanks.

http://www.charliegentle.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

here's a fiddle i did that had content sliding.  When the mouse enters the  the content slides in from left to right.  when the mouse leaves the  the content slides out from right to left and fades away.

[sliding Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NOLAnuffsaid/B27kx/4/)

```
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
$('li').animate({
    display: 'toggle',
    margin: '15px',
    opacity: '1'
}, 500);
```

});

```
$('div').mouseleave(function() {
$('li').animate({
    margin: '15px 0px 15px -100px',
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: '0'
}, 800).fadeToggle();
```

});​

Comment: Thank you for this, good JS effect. I was more interested in a static nav that slides in the content similar to that link. This is good though and will come in handy! Cheers!!

Comment: your welcome and glad i was able to help.  this is a big boost to my confidence knowing i helped you in some way.